# Convert cp850 to utf - Character Ð

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

I need to convert special characters (in this case Ð character) from cp850 to unicode and I am not being able to do it with mb_convert_encoding.
The correct conversion should be from Ð to Ñ in spanish but function mb_convert_enconding('Ð', 'utf-8') returns Ã.

Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply utf8_encode() to an already UTF8 string it will return a garbled UTF8 output.

I made a function that addresses all this issues. It´s called `Encoding::toUTF8()`.

You don't need to know what the encoding of your strings is. It can be Latin1 (iso 8859-1), Windows-1252 or UTF8, or the string can have a mix of them. `Encoding::toUTF8()` will convert everything to UTF8.

Usage:

```
require_once('Encoding.php'); 
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;  // It's namespaced now.
$utf8_string = Encoding::fixUTF8($garbled_utf8_string);
```

Download:

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

Examples:

```
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂÃÂ©dÃÂÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dération Camerounaise de Football");
```

will output:

```
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
```

I've transformed the function (forceUTF8) into a family of static functions on a class called Encoding. The new function is `Encoding::toUTF8()`.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the solution than just a simple code answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thanks for your answer but this did not work for the example given. The character stayed the same with different tests of the function. Maybe expanding the example could work. I am trying to go from ACUÐA to ACUÑA. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the source encoding:

```
print mb_convert_enconding('Ð', 'utf-8', 'CP850');
```

If you don't, the default order will be used to try to guess the original encoding, and it's usually detecting UTF8 and/or Latin1 first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this did not solve the issue. Maybe expanding the example could work. I am trying to go from ACUÐA to ACUÑA. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. If you are trying to convert the encoding, mb_convert_encoding should already work.
If the original string was wrongly encoded with an encoding that didn't support the character, your only option is to substitute them one by one with a str_replace and an array of correspondences.